# How to specify git branch in Yocto recipe

Tags: git, yocto, bitbake

I have two branches in my git repository. When I specify branch it gives me error.

```
Exception: bb.fetch2.MalformedUrl: The URL: 'branch=master;' is invalid and cannot be interpreted
```

Following is `SRC_URI` in my recipe

```
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/abc/abc.git; branch=master;"
```

If I don't specify branch then there is no issue.

What's the mistake in `SRC_URI`, I have referred other recipe's `SRC_URI` and they also follow the same syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a spurious space, (before specifying `branch=` please use

```
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/abc/abc.git;branch=master"
```

For more details see [Bitbake Documentation](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#git-fetcher)